# Logstash loses message when output not available?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I'm interested about what happen when Logstash fails to send events to output destination (for example, to a Kafka topic).

The single event will be lost or not? In case affermative, how to prevent losses?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be interested in [Persistent Queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html).

<sub>Would like to highlight one section of it, which seems extreme</sub>

> In order to protect against data loss during abnormal termination, Logstash has a persistent queue feature which will store the message queue on disk. Persistent queues provide durability of data within Logstash.
>
> Persistent queues are also useful for Logstash deployments that need large buffers. Instead of deploying and managing a message broker, such as Redis, RabbitMQ, or Apache Kafka, to facilitate a buffered publish-subscriber model, you can enable persistent queues to buffer events on disk and **remove the message broker**

But, I assume once queue is full, then messages would likely be dropped.

---

The alternative is to remove Logstash from the picture and use the Kafka Connect framework for external systems to Kafka, Filebeat/Fluentbit for watching file local changes, and Metricbeat/Telegraf for system metric monitoring.

Comment: Using persistent queue, if the output destination is not available (for example, Kafka service goes down), the event will be lost. Do you know if is possible to get some return codes for each processed message?

Comment: I have not used the persistent queues feature before, so I am not sure. In my experience, having each and every replica of a Kafka topic go down is highly unlikely, though